# Laravel query builder: reverse of "LIKE"?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I need the reverse of a LIKE comparison. For example, if my database contains a person with firstName "Daniel" and I search for first name "dan" then I want to get a hit. The query works when I use

`->where('firstName', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')`

What would I use if my database contains "Dan" and I want to get a hit when I search for "Daniel", but not when I search for "Steve"? Basically, I want the effect of putting the wildcard % around the field instead of around the search term.

I am using the query builder in Laravel 5.6

[edited for clarity]

Comment: You mean `not like`?

Comment: I don't think so. I would not want it to hit if I searched for "Steve".

Comment: Now I see what you mean. So if the first letters match, the database should return the value?

Comment: For me it doesn't make sense, so when you search for "Daniel" you would like to also find user with name "Doug" ? Well, it has letter D so why not? What about "Liz"? Again, it contains letter i and L, so you would like to also match this?

Comment: No, the entire field contents should be contained in the search string. So if "Dan" is the database field, it should be included in the results of searches for "Daniel" or "Danielle" or "Sedan" but not if the search was for "Steve" or "Doug" or "begonias".

Basically, I'd like to put the wildcard % around the field instead of around the search term.

Answer (score 2):

You can swap column and search term:

```php
->whereRaw("? LIKE CONCAT('%', `firstName`, '%')", [$searchTerm]);
```